# Define schema with default date 12 months in the future

Tags: prisma

How would I define an `endDate` to be 12 months in the future in my `schema.prisma`. For example:

```
model Subscription {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  startDate DateTime @default(now())
  endDate DateTime @default( How to define 1 year in the future?)
  ...
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good use for a db trigger

Comment: True, I could definitely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom function that returns the time after one year and call it via the [dbgenerated](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#dbgenerated) function.

Example: The function created in the database is called `get_end_time`. You can define it in schema as

```
model Subscription {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  startDate DateTime @default(now())
  endDate   DateTime @default(dbgenerated("get_end_time()"))
}
```